# Parent - Child - Grand Child category Markup in Codeigniter view

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a test Database Table by the name of autos like following

[image]

I am using a recursive function in my model to get the data in array and dumped it. It looks perfect like following

```
Array
(
[menu] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Automobiles
                [parent] => 0
                [child] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [name] => Honda
                                [parent] => 1
                                [child] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 3
                                                [name] => Cars
                                                [parent] => 2
                                                [child] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 4
                                                                [name] => Civic
                                                                [parent] => 3
                                                                [child] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [0] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [id] => 5
                                                                                [name] => Prosmetic
                                                                                [parent] => 4
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )
```

In my view I am creating a standard bootstrap [multi-level dropdown](http://Multi-Level%20Dropdowns) but I am not getting all the child menus

[image]

**Problem : I am not getting all the child**

I believe I have found the reason which is in my view code . Following is the code snippet which renders the drop-down

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php for($i=0;$i<count($menu);$i++){?>
            <?php if(!empty($menu[$i]['child'])){?>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" href="#"><?php echo $menu[$i]['name']?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php for($j=0;$j<count($menu[$i]['child']);$j++){?>
                            <li><a href="#"><?php echo $menu[$i]['child'][$j]['name']?></a></li>
                        <?php }?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <?php }else{?>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><?php echo $menu[$i]['name']?></a></li>
        <?php }}?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am only able to get First level child because I am only checking for the first level child. How can I do it repeatedly (recursively) in the view. I can't just keep checking for sub-child of a child and so on.. There has to be a way. Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

**EDIT: My Model**

```
function getCategoriesByParentId($category_id) {
    $data = $this->db->select('*')->from('autos')->WHERE('parent',$category_id)->get()->result_array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        if($this->getCategoriesByParentId($data[$i]['id']))
        {
            $data[$i]['child']=$this->getCategoriesByParentId($data[$i]['id']);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Test_model');
    $data['menu']=$this->Test_model->getCategoriesByParentId(0);
    //echo '<pre>';print_r(($data));echo '</pre>';exit;

    $data['title']='testing';
    $this->load->view('head',$data);
    $this->load->view('dropdown');
}
```

I inserted some more categories and subcategories. Now the Menu looks like this

[image]

Comment: add the output of $menu as code not in image

Comment: Image removed. out put in code format.

Comment: I haven't tested it but have a look at the function

function arrayToMenu($array)
 {
 $out = '<ul>';
 foreach ($array as $key => $elem)
 {
 $out .= '<li>'.$elem['name'].(!empty($elem['child']) ? arrayToMenu($elem['child']) : '').'</li>';
 }
 return $out.'</ul>';
 }

Comment: Thankyou @Snm this function works for single level

Comment: Why not use the same principle as in your recursive function in your model, for your view? Can you include how your recursive function looks like?

Comment: The problem is that `$menu` only has one item. The first `for` loop only runs once.

Comment: please see the edits

Comment: @DFriend - I have inserted more Data into my table. Now the first for loop runs twice

Comment: I think your structure is wrong. Let me think on it for awhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function might be of help. It could be placed in a helper file, and then you could call it from the view like `printMenu($menu);`

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE:**
If you need to exclude the first element in your array, as it seems that you want to identify it as a parent, you could do something like this:

**HELPER:** (for example `menu_helper.php` put in folder helper)

```
function printMenu($a) {

  if (!is_array($a)) {
    return;
  } 

  foreach($a as $m) {         
      if($m['parent'] > 0){
          echo '<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">'. $m['name'] .'</a></li>';             
      }

      if(is_array($m['child'])){
        printMenu($m['child']);
      }
  }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php if($has_children){ ?>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#"><?php echo $menu[0]['name']?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">                      
                    <?php printMenu($menu); ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php } else {?>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><?php echo $menu[0]['name']?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('menu'); // OUR NEW HELPER FILE
    $this->load->model('Test_model');
    $data['menu'] = $this->Test_model->getCategoriesByParentId(0);
    $data['has_children'] = 1; //REPLACE WITH A QUERY OR FUNCTION TO CHECK IF CHILDREN EXISTS IN YOU MENU
    $this->load->view('dropdown', $data);
}
```

The example above only applies to arrays with one single parent. If you need multiple parents you have to call the function for each parent. THis is not optimal, an if you need more advanced handling of menus with multiple depths in Codeigniter you could check the library in this project: https://github.com/edomaru/codeigniter_multilevel_menu

The library is not updated for a while and I don't know if its compatible with CI 3, but maybe you could get some ideas of how to go along by checking the source code. They even have a Bootstrap 3 example there.

Comment: So far the best answer I could get. Thanks @Michael K