# codeigniter tree view build data

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, while-loop

[This is the db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVyPg.png)

```
[
  {
    text: 'Parent 1',
    href: '#parent1',
    tags: ['4'],
    nodes: [
      {
        text: 'Child 1',
        href: '#child1',
        tags: ['2'],
        nodes: [
          {
            text: 'Grandchild 1',
            href: '#grandchild1',
            tags: ['0']
          },
          {
            text: 'Grandchild 2',
            href: '#grandchild2',
            tags: ['0']
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Child 2',
        href: '#child2',
        tags: ['0']
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent 2',
    href: '#parent2',
    tags: ['0']
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent 3',
    href: '#parent3',
     tags: ['0']
  }
]
```

The code i used is this,

```
public function getCategoryTree($level = 0, $prefix = '') {
        $rows = $this->db
            ->select('id,parent_id,name')
            ->where('parent_id', $level)
            ->order_by('id','asc')
            ->get('category')
            ->result();

        $json_response = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            $row_array = array();
            $row_array['text'] = $row->name;        
            $row_array['nodes'] = array();
            $newlevel = $row->id;  

        $childs = $this->db
            ->select('id,parent_id,name')
            ->where('parent_id', $newlevel)
            ->order_by('id','asc')
            ->get('category')
            ->result();

            if(count($childs) > 0){ 
                foreach ($childs as $row)
                {
                    $row_array['nodes'][] = array(
                        'text' => $row->name,
                    );
                }
            }
            array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
        }
        return $json_response;

    }
```

The output i got:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNYYK.png)

The above code gives only one level, but I want to go deep. How do I format the loops to get it done?

Comment: Do Not put  the db structure in an image.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these methods:

```
public function getCategoryTree()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('id,parent_id,name')
        ->order_by('parent_id','asc')
        ->get('categories');

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $result = $query->result_array();

        foreach( $result as $k => $v )
        {
            $count = 0;
            $v['href'] = '#'. strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $v['name']));

            foreach( $result as $k2 => $v2 )
            {
                // if child has this parent, count
                if( $v['id'] == $v2['parent_id'] )
                    $count++;
            }

            if( $count )
                $v['tags'] = array((string)$count);

            $mod[] = $v;
        }

        $tree = $this->buildTree($mod);

        $this->key_unset_recursive( $tree, 'id' );
        $this->key_unset_recursive( $tree, 'parent_id' );

        echo json_encode( $tree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
    }

}

public function buildTree( array $elements, $parentId = 0 )
{
    $branch = array();

    foreach( $elements as $element )
    {
        if( $element['parent_id'] == $parentId )
        {
            $children = $this->buildTree($elements, $element['id']);

            if( $children )
            {
                $element['nodes'] = $children;
            }

            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

public function key_unset_recursive( &$array, $remove )
{
    foreach( $array as $key => &$value )
    {
        if( $key === $remove )
        {
            unset( $array[$key] );
        }

        else if( is_array( $value ) )
        {
            $this->key_unset_recursive( $value, $remove );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a recursive function to achieve that. You can find your answer at [Parent - Child - Grand Child category Markup in Codeigniter view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293650/parent-child-grand-child-category-markup-in-codeigniter-view)